# Python argparse: can flag be optional for one argument?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a python script that uses argparse to look for more than 10 optional flags.

Is it possible to make the flag optional for one of the arguments? In my case it's the --time flag.

Normally I'd use it like this:

> ./myScript.pl --time 12:12:12 --date 2023-03-23 --flag2 dosomething

I want to be able to use it like this as well:

> ./myScript.pl 12:12:12 --date 2023-03-23 --flag2 dosomething

Comment: Options are *always* optional by default (you need to pass `require=True` to `add_argument` to change that). It's not clear what you are asking; your second command should work fine. `--date` and `--flag2` are also optional by default. If you want to make an option *conditionally* required based on the presence of some other option, you should probably look into subcommands instead.

Comment: An argument without a flag is a `positional`.  While `nargs` works with those, it's best to keep them simple.

Comment: To clarify. All my flags have default values. Sometime I only have to give it the time. I want to type ./myScript 12:12:12.2 instead of ./myScript --time 12:12:12.2. It's not just me being lazy, it's to make the script more useable by other people.

Comment: I solved my problem. I can capture any unflagged arguments with this then test to see if it's not empty.

a.add_argument('rest', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not how `argparse` is meant to be used, but you could combine a positional version of your argument and the keyword version of your argument in a mutually exclusive group, like so:

```py
import argparse

def get_parser():
    
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    time_group = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    time_group.add_argument("--time", required=False)  # Keyword version
    time_group.add_argument("time_pos", nargs="?")  # Positional version
    p.add_argument("--next-argument")
    return p
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_parser().parse_args("123 --next-argument foo".split()))
    # >>> Namespace(time=None, time_pos='123', next_argument='foo')
    print(get_parser().parse_args("--time 456 --next-argument foo".split()))
    # >>> Namespace(time='456', time_pos=None, next_argument='foo')
    print(get_parser().parse_args("123 --time 456 --next-argument foo".split()))
    # >>> error: argument --time: not allowed with argument time_pos
    print(get_parser().parse_args("--next-argument foo".split()))
    # >>> error: one of the arguments --time time_pos is required
```

Unfortunately, I did not find a way to have both `time` and `time_pos` be output under the same Namespace key (in particular, setting `dest="time_pos"` does not work for `time`), so you would need to check both the values of `time` and `time_pos` for the user input or None. However, with the required mutually exclusive group, you can at least be sure that exactly one of both is given.